# Does {$a_2,a_3$} define a basic feasible solution for the Linear Program?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-programming

**Question:** Consider the following linear program
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\text{Minimize} \ x_2 \\
\text{subject to} \ x_1+ x_2 +x_3 = 4\\
-2x_1+x_2 = -3\\
x_1,x_2,x_3 \ge 0 \\
\end{split}
\end{equation}

Does $B = \{a_2,a_3\}$ define a BFS?

**My attempt**

I believe it doesn't represent a linear program because I work out $B^{-1}b$ which equals 
$\left[
    \begin{array}{c}
      -3\\
      0
    \end{array}
\right] $

Which is negative therefore cannot be a BFS, is this correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're correct except for the value of $B^{-1}b = \left[
    \begin{array}{c}
      -3\\
      \color{red}7
    \end{array}
\right]$.

It is not a BFS (basic *feasible* solution) because you require $x_1,x_2,x_3 \ge 0$, but $-7 < 0$.  However, you can still begin with this basic *infeasible* solution to find a baisc *feasible* solution by the dual simplex algorithm.

Tranform the problem into

\begin{array}{lllll}
\max z &= &-x_2 & & \\
\text{s.t} & x_1 &+ x_2 &+ x_3 &= 4 \\
& -2x_1 &+ x_2 & &= -3 \\
& & &x_1,x_2,x_3 &\ge 0
\end{array}

You've chosen $B = \{a_2,a_3\} = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 \\ 1 & 0\end{bmatrix}$ and $c = (0,-1,0)^T$, so $B^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix}0 & 1 \\ 1 & -1\end{bmatrix}$, $c_B = (-1,0)^T$.

\begin{align}
B^{-1}A &= \begin{bmatrix}-2 & 1 & 0 \\ 3 & 0 & 1\end{bmatrix} \\
B^{-1}b &= \begin{bmatrix}-3 \\ 7\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}

The simplex tableau is

\begin{array}{c|c}
B^{-1}A & B^{-1}b \\ \hline
c_B B^{-1}A - c^T & c_B B^{-1}b
\end{array}

\begin{array}{rrrr|r}
      & x_1 & x_2 & x_3 &    \\ \hline
  x_2 &  -2 &   1 &   0 & -3 \\
  x_3 &   3 &   0 &   1 &  7 \\ \hline
    z &   2 &   0 &   0 &  3
\end{array}

The only choice of pivot element is $y_{12}$, so $x_2$ is the leaving variable, while $x_1$ is the entering variable.

\begin{array}{rrrr|r}
      & x_1 &      x_2 & x_3 &         \\ \hline
  x_1 &   1 &  \frac12 &   0 & \frac32 \\
  x_3 &   0 & -\frac32 &   1 & \frac52 \\ \hline
    z &   0 &        1 &   0 &       0
\end{array}

Therefore, the optimal BFS of the problem is $\left(\dfrac32,0,\dfrac52\right)^T$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!